# What is $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{25y^2-10y-3}}dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{25y^2-10y-3}}dy$

$= \int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(5y-1)^2-4}}dy$

$=\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u^2-4}}\dfrac{du}{5}, \quad U$ substitution

$=\int \dfrac{1}{10\cos(\theta)} 2\cos(\theta) d\theta, \quad$ Trig substitution

$= \dfrac{1}{5} \theta$

$= \dfrac{\cos^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{(5y-1)^2-4}}{2}}{5} +C$

Where did I go wrong?

work after u substitution $\frac{1}{5}\int \sec \theta d\theta \\ =\frac{1}{5} \ln \left |  \sec \theta + \tan \theta\right | $

*** New Answer*** $\\
\frac{1}{5}\ln \left | \frac{5y-1}{2} +\frac{\sqrt{(5y-1)^2 -4}}{2}\right | +C$

Comment: Uh-you sure it's wrong? lol Seriously,though-how'd you get the last step-a geometric definition of theta? Sorry,I'm tired and it's not clear to me where you got it.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 I just edited it the 2 wasn't supposed to be in the square root, but i had $u=2sin\theta$ so I made a triangle off that.

Comment: @Tyler Since you have an irreducible quadratic, a better method might be to complete the square and then perform a trig substitution.

Comment: Looks ok to me,but it IS a pretty gnarly computation,so you really would like to check it with a computer algebra program.

Comment: @Jun-GooKwak Thats what I did

Comment: @Jun-GooKwak He did that,the problem was in the last step.

Comment: @Tyler Right, I see now.

Comment: @Tyler you messed up on evaluating $\sec \sec^{-1} \theta \text{ and }\tan \sec^{-1} \theta$

Comment: @MathNoob was it just the addition sign? that was just a typo

Comment: @Tyler no, sec(asec($x$))=$x$, tan(asec($x$))=\sqrt{x^2-1}$$

Comment: @MathNoob I'm not sure what you are trying to say

Comment: $\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{25y^2-10y-3}}dy
=\frac15 \tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{25y^2-10y-3}}{5y-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the 3rd line. $$\sqrt{4\sin^2\theta-4} \neq 2\cos \theta$$
Try $x=2\cosh\theta$ or $x=2\sec\theta$

Comment: ahh would it be $-cos\theta$

Comment: No it would not. $1-\sin^2\theta= -\cos^2\theta$, but you cannot take a complex root.

Comment: @MathNoob Ah,were it only that simple.

Comment: i mean using the formula $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$

Comment: $\sin^2\theta - 1 = -\cos^2\theta$

Comment: $$\sqrt{4\sin^2\theta-4}=\sqrt{4(\sin^2\theta-1)}=\sqrt{-4\cos^2\theta}=2i\cos \theta$$

Comment: oh ya you'd get a complex number

Comment: i see my mistake, I should have originally subbed x for sec not sin

Comment: @MathNoob I updated my question with my revised answer

Comment: @Tyler Can you show me your revised work as well?

Comment: @MathNoob theres a few lines

Comment: @Tyler $\int \sec \theta\neq \log |\csc\theta-\cot\theta|$

Comment: @MathNoob i accidentally wrote the wrong identity down, I'll fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20709/discussion-between-tyler-and-mathnoob).